# How to determine $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{n!}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra

Given $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ & 2 \end{bmatrix}$,

$e^A$ is computed by the formula

$e^A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  \\ & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \frac{1}{1!}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ & 2 \end{bmatrix} + \frac{1}{2!}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ & 4 \end{bmatrix} + \dots = \begin{bmatrix} e & * \\ & e^2 \end{bmatrix}$.

I am trying to figure out what $*$ is in the above formula.

By calculating $A^n$,

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ & 2 \end{bmatrix}$,

$A^2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ & 2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1+2 \\ & 2^2 \end{bmatrix}$,

$A^n=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1+2+2^2+\dots+2^{n-1} \\ & 2^n \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{2^n-1}{2-1} \\ & 2^n \end{bmatrix}$.

Thus $* = \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{n!}$.

My question is (1) whether I came to the right place until now, (2) if the sum $*$ exists and (3) if so, what it is(does it have a explicit formula).

Comment: For series look to exponent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function

Comment: What is the lower left entry?  Zero?  Same as upper entry?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Zero it is.

Comment: How do you compute those matrices in the expansion of $e^A$? They look off to me.

Comment: @TonyK You may consult [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=matrix+exponential&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKR830KR830&oq=matrix+expo&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l2j46j0l3.7242j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: But $A^0\ne\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and $A^2\ne\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ & 3 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @TonyK Oh there's a typo. Thanks I modified

Comment: Also your expression for $A^n$ should have $2^n$ in the bottom right, not $2$.

Comment: @TonyK Correct!

Comment: And finally, $* = \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{n!}$, not $1+\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{n!}$. I think I'm done now.

Comment: @TonyK I modified all the typos you pointed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use the fact that
$$
e^x = \sum_{n\geq 0} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^n - 1}{n!} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \dfrac{2^n - 1^n}{n!} = e^2 - e^1 = e^2 - e.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It does converge, for example by the ratio test.

You can find the limit by splitting the sum into two: it's $\sum \frac{2^n}{n!} - \sum \frac{1}{n!}$. Both of these you can recognise from $e^x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is a powerseries with radius of convergence $R=+\infty$.
Thus both $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{n!}$ and $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{n!}=-\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=-\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1^n}{n!}$ are convergent.
Take the sum of two.

Answer (score 1):

By the ratio test

$$\frac{2-2^{-n}}{n+1}\le\frac34$$ as soon as $n>1$.

(Of course, you can split the two terms and use the well-known Taylor development.)